# JQuery Mobile: modifying <a> button data-inline="true" using CSS @media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'd like for my buttons to only be inline in certain browser widths.

Can this be done with CSS?

Failing that, can this be done with Javascript (fire a function when screen layout changes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using `display: inline-block` actually works for me right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use CSS resposive design techniques with attribute selectors to affect these elements.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    a[data-inline=true] {
        display:inline;
    }
}
```

Comment: This selects it (which is handy) but does not let me *set* the `data-inline` attribute.